# Laravel won't load my javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have a javascript file in `/public/js/` called `myjavascript.js` .

I want to include it in my site.

So I did this:

```
@extends('something')

    @section('scripts')
        <script src="/js/myjavascript.js"></script>
    @stop

@section('content')
...
```

This work in other project but not in this new one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your path is correct or not

Comment: provide full path of your .js file like `src="<?php echo asset('/js/myjavascript.js'); ?>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/myjavascript.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script rel="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/myjavascript.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: or the shorter helper function `asset()`

Comment: or just <script src="{{ asset('/js/myjavascript.js') }}"></script> :)

Comment: That's what i suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code need to update like:

```
{!! Html::script('js/myjavascript.js') !!}
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 1):

`<script src="{{ asset('/js/myjavascript.js') }}"></script>` is perfect.

Check your APP_URL from .env file.

if your APP_URL=www.example.com 
then your source will be **www.example.com/js/myjavascript.js**

if your APP_URL=example.com/laravel
then your source will be **www.example.com/laravel/js/myjavascript.js**
Check  'https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php' for more about asset helper function